# LNK2005 of death (c++)

Tags: c++, include, lnk2005

I have a simple class:

**Bunny.h**

```
class Bunny
{
public: 
    Bunny(string givenName);
    ~Bunny();    
private:
    string name;
};
```

**Bunny.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "Bunny.h"
Bunny(string givenName)
{
     name = givenName;
};
```

(I rewrote the code because I can't copy it, so it's only a quickly written example)

An includes.h file     #include s this, and source.cpp    #include s that one. Each file is only included once, and source.cpp only includes the includes.h file once. I did try it with #ifndef, #define, #endif.
Both of these methods resulted in the same issue: the compiler says that this function (and any other one that I add) are multiply declared. 
I also tried to just copy the definitions over to source.cpp (both Bunny.h and Bunny.cpp copied as is) and the errors disappeared.

Any idea why the compiler is defining this function twice

Comment: `Bunny(string givenName)` -> `Bunny::Bunny(string givenName)` in your `.cpp`.

Comment: Move `#pragma once` to Bunny.h

Comment: You should include the **exact** error message in your question.

Comment: Prefer using the initialization list to initialize members instead of using the constructor body: `Bunny::Bunny(string givenName) : name(givenName) { }` - it exists for a reason; to avoid first defailt initialization followed by assignment.

Comment: `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;` are missing somewhere.

Comment: @Michael Walz a [mcve] is what's *really* missing.

Comment: the problem was that in the includes.h file u was including the Bunny.cpp file instead of Bunny.h.   @MichaelWalz i can't copy the exact code as i said... i know it would've been better but that pc is not connected to the internet

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the Includes.h file, I included the Bunny.cpp instead of Bunny.h file. Then the compiler defined the functions twice, once in the cpp and once in includes.h.